# Rails based EC2 AMI

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I trying to navigate my new EC2 setup and was hoping to find an AMI setup for Rails.  I've been having trouble.  Basically, I'm looking for something like this:

```
* Apache 2.2
* Ruby Enterprise Edtion (REE)
* Passenger
* MySql Installed and configured with Ruby
```

Anyone have an AMI with a basic rails stack they could point me to?

#### Moved Answer up here:

Thanks for the responses/ideas. I've seen most of these options. I think I'm going to go with a clean Linux AMI, and then use something like this to customize it myself:

http://www.rubyinside.com/how-to-install-a-ruby-18-stack-on-ubuntu-810-from-scratch-1566.html

Also, yes I plan on running Rails on a single EC2 instance as an alternative to a VPS. If I use a reserved instance I can get basically a dedicated machine and 1.7GB of RAM for about $22 per month. That beats any VPS I've found. There are other costs and burdens, but I'm going to continue investigating if it is possible.

Thanks.

Comment: Out of curiosity how did this project end up going ? Anything you would share for someone in a similar place a few years later ?

Comment: I'm using [AWS Elastic Beanstalk](http://aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/).<br/><br/>
There is a doc for [Deploying a Rails Application](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_Ruby_rails.html), a Toolkit for Eclipse, etc. The walk through is also great.<br/><br/>
For me, the only thing missing is support for Postgres. But I hope they will do it soon.<br/>
I would have put the other links, but I don't have enough reputation for that :D<br/>
Hope it helps.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

First-off, are you planning to run Rails on a single EC2 instance? While possible, that's not really where EC2 shines, and you can get a simpler and cheaper setup on a VPS such as Slicehost, Linode, or Webbynode. EC2 is great for clustered setups with dedicated databases, multiple Rails servers, load balancers, etc., particularly if you need to be able to quickly scale up or down. But at that point, a single preconfigured AMI isn't going to do much good.

Having said that: Some time last year I used [EC2 on Rails](http://ec2onrails.rubyforge.org/). It's decent, but not very flexible. It also uses mongrel_cluster instead of Passenger. Apparently there's a way to set up a cluster, but frankly at that point there are probably better alternatives.

I've heard great things about [Rubber](http://wiki.github.com/wr0ngway/rubber) as a way to provision and deploy a Rails app on an EC2 cluster. It seems very flexible, yet fairly easy to get started with, and should scale nicely from single to multiple instances.

For more complex setups, I would probably be tempted to look at [Chef](http://wiki.opscode.com/display/chef/Home) as well, but I don't have any first-hand experience with it.

[PoolParty](http://auser.github.com/poolparty/), which sits on top of Chef, also seems worth a look.

Answer (score 8):

I highly suggest not using an AMI that has that stuff "preinstalled".

Instead, you want to use Chef as part of your deploy process. You can get [cookbooks](http://cookbooks.opscode.com/) for most of the things you just listed.

Save all that, I highly recommend EY's cloud service.

Answer (score 2):

I myself were looking for such an AMI but could not find it so finally went for deploying Ruby and Rails3 from scratch as mentioned here .. http://blog.enbake.com/setting-up-rails-3-stack-on-an-amazon-ec2-instance/

Answer (score 2):

BitNami has a free, preconfigured [Rails EC2 image](http://bitnami.org/stack/rubystack#cloudImage) that we keep fairly up to date

Answer (score 0):

I have used Paul Dowman's ec2onrails to host a production app for a while now. I'm looking in to [Rubber](http://wiki.github.com/wr0ngway/rubber) these days.