# Rails 3 Server on EC2

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-ec2, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I'm trying to setup a production server for a rails 3 app on a single amazon ec2 instance, and am wondering what route to take.

I'm quite new to deploying rails apps - is there a pre-existing ami I can use for rails3?

Any tips/wisdom/advice appreciated - thanks!

Comment: you might want to take a look at heroku? http://www.heroku.com/ you do not get access to the actual server, it is a ruby platform that is running on amazon cloud and makes deployment much easier

Comment: also a google search turned up this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1653101/rails-based-ec2-ami which links to this http://ec2onrails.rubyforge.org/

Comment: @house9, I've looked at heroku already, and their prices are huge for us compared to a linode vm ($20/m). I'm trying out amazon's free service, which is why I wanted resources specific to ec2. Regarding the other link, I've looked them up, but they're a bit outdated. Thanks for the suggestions though!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd like to suggest to use verified EC2 AMIs, for instance by [Rightscale](http://blog.rightscale.com/2011/04/29/rightscale-ready-ubuntu-11-04-amazon-amis/). You can not use the Rightscale as a service, but theirs AMIs are pretty stable and reliable.

UPDATE: I advice to use Amazon Linux Machine based on CentOS 6

Comment: you can install Rails environment by yourself, it's pretty easy today

Comment: @mikahilov, yes, but getting a server stack setup properly is still quite tedious in my opinion.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation of verified AMIs! Is there an advantage to using the Rightscale ones compared to the Ubuntu AMIs from the ubuntu site?

Comment: Just looking into Rightscale, and their quick start macros look like they are exactly what I need. Are there any other tools like Rightscale that are worth looking into? Thanks for the link!

Comment: We use the Rightscale service to manage the server templates to keep changes tracking, but we really don't need it now. Price is about $500/month for their paid account is not a good start. But their AMI are very reliable and rootkit-free, which is good to know

Comment: neat - thanks! I've definitely had trouble with some of the default templates, I think I might have to make my own.

Comment: yes, you can do your custom private AMI. it will help you to clone number of instances. Amazon AWS has a great web interface that can use their API. There is so much functionality: allocate Elastic IPs, Security Groups (analogue of iptables), initiate/boot/reboot/stop/terminate instances, build LoadBalanced, use Message Queues, Mail hosting instances, Wowza Media instance and much more

Comment: I tried the Rightscale image and Passenger and never could get it working - its like it was never able to find my site. Any other recommendations?

Comment: double check your firewall and system config. It works for us for years!

Answer (score 2):

In terms of reasonably priced EC2 management services check out [scalr.com](http://scalr.com/).

As for gems that makes it easier to deploy Rails to EC2 have a look at [Poolparty](https://github.com/auser/poolparty) and [Rubber](https://github.com/wr0ngway/rubber).

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu has a nice guide on EC2 and Ubuntu images. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EC2StartersGuide

Also see http://alestic.com/ I just set up one of these images on my EC2 free usage tier with no issues.