# ec2 deployments in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-ec2, capistrano

I know this question has probably been asked so many times here, but I didn't really find a good answer. I'm trying to find a simplest solution to do basically just checkout a git project on an ec2 instance, checkout a specific branch and then restart apache server.

I'm not sure if Capistrano is what I need. I'm fine with some shell script or ruby script which basically just invokes commands like 'git clone....', 'git checkout branch...' and 'restart apache server'

Is there a framework which lets me do this so I don't really have to write a script from scratch.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rails based EC2 AMI](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1653101/rails-based-ec2-ami)

Comment: If you "know this question has probably been asked so many times here" why didn't you search first?

Comment: I tried but I didn't really get a good answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, are we talking about "Deployment" or about "just get a codebase and copy to the server"?

In the first case, Deployment is a set of common practices, as following:

- "server" as abstractions
- keep versions and rollback ability
- database migration, rollback and backup functionality
- manage background processing

It's actually mean manage the full-stack application, not only "restart httpd" or something else.

Capistrano developed with 37signals contributions and they are using it on many projects. A lot of projects use capistrano or the same tool to do deployments. Look at this again, it's easy to setup and use.